# PHP - Create a new array using list of array keys in dot notation

Tags: php, arrays

I'm in the process of building a REST API and all data is being returned as JSON. Each request is funneled through a single function that does the job of setting HTTP status codes, returning messages or data, setting headers, etc. I also allow users to add a `?fields=` parameter where they can specify what fields they want returned (e.g `?fields=id,hostnames,ip_addresses`), if the parameter is not present they of course get all the data returned. The function that does this is also part of the function mentioned earler that sets the headers/data/messages, etc. What I want to be able to do is allow the user to specify field names using dot notation so they can specify fields from something other than a top-level field. So for example, I have a structure like this:

```
{
    "id": "8a2b449111b449409c465c66254c6fcc",
    "hostnames": [
        "webapp1-sfo",
        "webapp1-sfo.example.com"
    ],
    "ip_addresses": [
        "12.26.16.10",
        "ee80::ae56:2dff:fd89:7868"
    ],
    "environment": "Production",
    "data_center": "sfo",
    "business_unit": "Operations",
    "hardware_type": "Server",
    "currently_in_maintenance": false,
    "history": [
        {
            "id": 58,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-01-27 00:40:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-01-27 01:45:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG123456",
            "reason": "January production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/58"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 104,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-02-25 14:36:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-02-25 18:36:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG456789",
            "reason": "February production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/104"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 143,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-03-17 00:30:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-03-17 01:55:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG789123",
            "reason": "March production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/143"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this function, I can pull out top level fields (where `$mData` is the data structure above, and `$sParams` is the string of fields requested by the user):

```
private function removeFields($mData, $sParams){
    $clone = $mData;  // Clone the original data
    $fields = explode(',', $sParams);

    // Remove fields not requested by the user

    foreach($mData as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array((string)$key, $fields)){
            unset($mData[$key]);
        }
    }

    // If no fields remain, restore the original data
    // Chances are the user made a typo in the fields list

    if(count($mData) == 0){
        $mData = $clone;
    }

    return $mData;
}
```

Note: `$sParams` comes in as a string and is what is provided by the user (comma separated list of fields they want to see).

So `?fields=hostnames,history` would return:

```
{
    "hostnames": [
        "webapp1-sfo",
        "webapp1-sfo.example.com",
    ],
    "history": [
        {
            "id": 58,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-01-27 00:40:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-01-27 01:45:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG123456",
            "reason": "January production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/58"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 104,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-02-25 14:36:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-02-25 18:36:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG456789",
            "reason": "February production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/104"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 143,
            "time_start_utc": "2013-03-17 00:30:00",
            "time_end_utc": "2013-03-17 01:55:00",
            "ticket_number": "CHG789123",
            "reason": "March production maintenance",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "self",
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/143"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I want to return maybe just the `ticket_number` field from `history` I want the user to be able to do `?fields=history.ticket_number` or if they want the ticket number and link they could do this: `?fields=history.ticket_number,history.links.link`...which would return:

```
{
    "history": [
        {
            "ticket_number": "CHG123456",
            "links": [
                {
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/58"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ticket_number": "CHG456789",
            "links": [
                {
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/104"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ticket_number": "CHG789123",
            "links": [
                {
                    "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/143"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried many different array access methods for dot notation from stack overflow but they all break when the value of `history` is a numeric array...so for instance, using the methods I've found online so far I would need to do something like this to achieve the same output above (which obviously is not good...especially when you have hundreds of records).

`?fields=history.0.ticket_number,history.0.links.0.link,history.1.ticket_number,history.1.links.0.link,history.2.ticket_number,history.2.links.0.link,`

I was also looking for something that was dynamic and recursive as each API endpoint returns a different data structure (for instance, when a collection is requested it returns a numeric array filled with associative arrays..or in json speak, an array of objects...and some of those objects may have arrays (numeric or associative)).

Thanks in advance

P.S. - I don't really care if the code creates a new data array containing the requested data or directly manipulates the original data (as it does in my removeFields() function).

UPDATE: I've created a PHPFiddle that should hopefully show the issue I've been running into. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tw1i-qu7s

Comment: So to be clear, you need PHP to parse a GET request that may or may not have dot-delineated levels, then return only those records?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A user may provide an optional `fields` parameter via GET that will be processed on the server side with PHP. If it is provided it may contain a comma separated list of top-level fields (`?fields=hostnames,data_center,history`) or a dot-delineated list of values to extract data at a lower level (`?fields=history.id,history.ticket_number`) or both (`?fields=hostnames,data_centers,history.ticket_number`). Basically, the user could provided any combination of available array keys, each being separated by a comma....which I then explode into an array and process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your tips and help on this. I actually came up with a solution this morning that seems to work with every case I have tested so far. It may not be super elegant but works for what I need. I essentially flatten the array using dot notation for the keys in the flattened array. I then take each of the requested fields and build a regex (basically replacing any "." with a an optional `.[digit].` to catch numeric indexes), then test each field name using the regex, keeping those that match. Finally, I re-expand the array back into a multi-dimensional array.

The flattened array turns into this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 8a2b449111b449409c465c66254c6fcc
    [hostnames.0] => webapp1-sfo
    [hostnames.1] => webapp1-sfo.example.com
    [ip_addresses.0] => 12.26.16.10
    [ip_addresses.1] => ee80::ae56:2dff:fd89:7868
    [environment] => Production
    [data_center] => sfo
    [business_unit] => Operations
    [hardware_type] => Server
    [currently_in_maintenance] => 
    [history.0.id] => 58
    [history.0.time_start_utc] => 2013-01-27 00:40:00
    [history.0.time_end_utc] => 2013-01-27 01:45:00
    [history.0.ticket_number] => CHG123456
    [history.0.reason] => January production maintenance
    [history.0.links.0.rel] => self
    [history.0.links.0.link] => https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/58
    [history.1.id] => 104
    [history.1.time_start_utc] => 2013-02-25 14:36:00
    [history.1.time_end_utc] => 2013-02-25 18:36:00
    [history.1.ticket_number] => CHG456789
    [history.1.reason] => February production maintenance
    [history.1.links.0.rel] => self
    [history.1.links.0.link] => https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/104
    [history.2.id] => 143
    [history.2.time_start_utc] => 2013-03-17 00:30:00
    [history.2.time_end_utc] => 2013-03-17 01:55:00
    [history.2.ticket_number] => CHG789123
    [history.2.reason] => March production maintenance
    [history.2.links.0.rel] => self
    [history.2.links.0.link] => https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/143
)
```

Below are the two functions for flattening and expanding the array:

```
function flattenArray($aArrayToFlatten, $sSeparator = '.', $sParentKey = NULL){
    if(!is_array($aArrayToFlatten)){
        return $aArrayToFlatten;
    }
    $_flattened = array();

    // Rewrite keys

    foreach($aArrayToFlatten as $key => $value){
        if($sParentKey !== NULL){
            $key = $sParentKey . $sSeparator . $key;
        }
        $_flattened[$key] = flattenArray($value, $sSeparator, $key);
    }

    // Flatten

    $flattened = array();
    foreach($_flattened as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $flattened = array_merge($flattened, $value);
        }else{
            $flattened[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $flattened;
}

function expandArray($aFlattenedArray, $sSeparator = '.'){
    $result = array();
    foreach($aFlattenedArray as $key => $val){
        $keyParts = explode($sSeparator, $key);
        $currentArray = &$result;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($keyParts) - 1; $i++){
            if(!isset($currentArray[$keyParts[$i]])){
                $currentArray[$keyParts[$i]] = array();
            }
            $currentArray = &$currentArray[$keyParts[$i]];
        }
        $currentArray[$keyParts[count($keyParts)-1]] = $val;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Example:

```
$mData = json_decode('{ "id": "8a2b449111b449409c465c66254c6fcc", "hostnames": [ "webapp1-sfo", "webapp1-sfo.example.com" ], "ip_addresses": [ "12.26.16.10", "ee80::ae56:2dff:fd89:7868" ], "environment": "Production", "data_center": "sfo", "business_unit": "Operations", "hardware_type": "Server", "currently_in_maintenance": false, "history": [ { "id": 58, "time_start_utc": "2013-01-27 00:40:00", "time_end_utc": "2013-01-27 01:45:00", "ticket_number": "CHG123456", "reason": "January production maintenance", "links": [ { "rel": "self", "link": "https:\/\/localhost\/api\/v1\/maintenances\/58" } ] }, { "id": 104, "time_start_utc": "2013-02-25 14:36:00", "time_end_utc": "2013-02-25 18:36:00", "ticket_number": "CHG456789", "reason": "February production maintenance", "links": [ { "rel": "self", "link": "https:\/\/localhost\/api\/v1\/maintenances\/104" } ] }, { "id": 143, "time_start_utc": "2013-03-17 00:30:00", "time_end_utc": "2013-03-17 01:55:00", "ticket_number": "CHG789123", "reason": "March production maintenance", "links": [ { "rel": "self", "link": "https:\/\/localhost\/api\/v1\/maintenances\/143" } ] } ] }', TRUE);

print_r($mData);   // Original Data

$fields = array("id", "hostnames", "history.id", "history.links.link");
$regexFields = array();

// Build regular expressions for each of the requested fields

foreach($fields as $dotNotatedFieldName){

    // Requested field has a dot in it -- it's not a top-level field
    // It may be part of a collection (0.fieldname.levelTwo, 1.fieldName.levelTwo,...) or be a collection (fieldName.0.levelTwo, fieldName.1.levelTwo, ...)

    if(preg_match('/\./', $dotNotatedFieldName)){
        $regexFields[] = "^\d*\.?" . str_replace(".", "\.\d*\.?", $dotNotatedFieldName);

    // Requested field does not have a dot in it -- it's a top-level field
    // It may be part of a collection (0.fieldname, 1.fieldName,...) or be a collection (fieldName.0, fieldName.1, ...)

    }else{
        $regexFields[] = "^\d*\.?" . $dotNotatedFieldName . "\.?\d*";
    }
}

// Flatten the array

$flattened = flattenArray($mData);

// Test each flattened key against each regular expression and remove those that don't match

foreach($flattened as $key => $value){
    $matchFound = FALSE;

    foreach($regexFields as $regex){
        if(preg_match('/' . $regex . '/', $key)){
            $matchFound = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($matchFound === FALSE){
        unset($flattened[$key]);
    }

}

// Expand the array

$mData = expandArray($flattened);

print_r(json_encode($mData));  // New Data
```

Which outputs the following JSON:

```
{
   "id": "8a2b449111b449409c465c66254c6fcc",
   "hostnames": [
      "webapp1-sfo",
      "webapp1-sfo.example.com"
   ],
   "history": [
      {
         "id": 58,
         "links": [
            {
               "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/58"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": 104,
         "links": [
            {
               "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/104"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": 143,
         "links": [
            {
               "link": "https://localhost/api/v1/maintenances/143"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This solution is really clever. I have a similar problem of my own that I just now realised this solution could be applied to. If, while working on this further, you find a way to improve it, would you mind updating this answer?

Comment: If I improve this answer I'll be sure to post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing fields from your clone it would be easy to loop on fields and then get each of them into your clone

You need a function for having dot notation to traverse your json. Like this one https://selvinortiz.com/blog/traversing-arrays-using-dot-notation

```
private function buildResponse($mData, $sParams){
    $fields = explode(',', $sParams['fields']);
    $response = $mData;

     if (count($fields > 0)){
       $response = [];
       foreach($fields as $value){
         if (getDotValue($mData, $value)){
           $response[$value] = $mData.getDotValue($value);
         }
       }
     }

     return json_encode($response);
}
```

Code is not tested but you can understand my point.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.I gave this a try (which is similar to other things I have found and tried as well) but it still doesn't quite give me what I need. The issue lies with the nested arrays that are numerically keyed because they can't be accessed "directly" or easily because the user would need to specify `history.0.id,history.1.id,history.2.id`, etc instead of just a single `history.id` to get only the `id` from every `history` entry. I've created a PHPFiddle that hopefully shows the issue. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tw1i-qu7s

Answer (score 0):

Run a check

```
if (isset($field=>$nextfield)) { //if next field level is named
  //do magic here
} else if (isset($field[0])) { //if next field level is indexed
  for ($i=0; $i < count($field); $i++) { 
    //catch 'em all
  }
}
```

For example, `history.id` would catch the `if` on `history`, the `else if` on the numbered indexes, then the `if` for the `id`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I actually found a working solution this morning though. It has been posted if you are curious. Thanks again